# Notepad++ Recognize Alternate Extensions

Tags: notepad++

I am writing Hive scripts and always need to manually set the language to "SQL" if I want any sort of color which lead me to wonder if there is a way to teach NP++ to recognize alternate extensions for a language in general.

For instance, if I open a hive script with a .hql or .q extension, I would like to default the language to "SQL".

If this is not possible for a built in language -- is it possible to change for a custom language (SAS, Pig Latin, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions are in `langs.model.xml` in the Notepad++ installation directory. they go in the `ext` attribute on the `Language` tag. This is a space-separated list of extensions without the `.`.